# Python scipy optimization does not find minimum

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

Trying to use `scipy.optimize.minimize`, it seems like the optimization fails. I did the following:
1. The objective function is: `f(x)= x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+10`
2. The constraint is: `x_i >= 0`
3. The initial guess is: `x0 = [1,1,1,1]`
Very trivial problem, with the optimal solution `x=[0,0,0,0], f(x)=10`.
The code:

```
def pos(x):
    return min(x)
def f1(p):
    return (p[0] + p[1] + p[2] +p[3] + 10)
cons2 = ({'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : pos})
x0 = np.array([1,1,1,1])
res = opt.minimize(f1, x0,method='SLSQP',constraints=cons2)
```

I get the following result:

```
 fun: 100543626.59510386
 jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev: 54
 nit: 9
njev: 9
status: 0
success: True
   x: array([ 24128556.46553156,  24130378.42917114,  28154390.61929696,
    24130291.0811042 ])
```

Which is clearly wrong answer (but the success flag is true).
I know that there are some assumptions "f" must follow, but in this case "f" is just an hyperplane, so I am really confused. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
def pos(x):
    return min(x)
```

with

```
def pos(x):
    return x
```

(The inequality constraint function can return a vector; each component of the vector must satisfy the constraint.)

The two formulations seem mathematically equivalent, but something about your version breaks the calculation.  It might be because the SLSQP algorithm assumes that the constraint function is differentiable, and `min(x)` is not differentiable.